# Python + Selenium: Unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to locate a tab and click it on my webpage. However, my code does not work:

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tab_bd3ae39d-f956-49ab-b7bd-f13507de9351']/div[2]/div")).perform()
additionaldata_ele= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tab_bd3ae39d-f956-49ab-b7bd-f13507de9351']/div[2]/div").click()
```

The HTML body is as follows:

```
<li class="WJX1 WLV1" id="tab_015ba30c-af6c-4c9a-ac34-f77ee00805b6" role="tab" aria-controls="tabPanel_16845ddd-961b-4581-89da-a6a4e6080930" data-automation-id="tab" aria-selected="false"><div class="WGX1"></div><div class="WEX1"><div class="gwt-Label WLX1" data-automation-id="tabLabel">Additional Data</div></div></li>
```

I get the error -

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='tab_bd3ae39d-f956-49ab-b7bd-f13507de9351']/div[2]/div"}
```

I guess the reason is that when I try to find the element, it doesn't appear on the DOM, so I should implement WebDriverWait until the element is visible. So I tried WebDriverWait, but it didn't work either.

Many thanks for all answers and replies!

**second edition:**
Here is the webpage, sorry I cannot share the link, it is an internal webpage and PSW is required:

[This is the screenshot of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rAhm.png)

Comment: Please add a link to the web page and clarify what element you trying to access there?

Comment: What do you mean by `I'm trying to locate a tab` ? - does that mean the element is in new tab or window ?

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. This is an internal webpage and PSW is required, so I added one screenshot of the page, hope it will help.

Comment: It's not a new window. It is a tab on the webpage, when I click the tab, part of the webpage will be refreshed and new content will appear.

Answer (score 2):

That `id` looks dynamic - it will probably change frequently and result in an unstable script.

Additionally, you will want a wait to ensure your web page is ready before you continue.

try something like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[text()="Additional Data"]'))).click()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works for other elements. However, it does not work on this element, here is the error: selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message
I think it is because of my wrong Xpath, but I don't what is the correct Xpath

Comment: @BigJay This is a great free learning resource to learn how to identify web element: https://testautomationu.applitools.com/web-element-locator-strategies/   - invest a few hours and you can do it like a pro

Comment: Appreciate it! Thank you so much!